# Reading from a text file, best way to store data C++

Tags: c++, file, input, tryparse

Basicly I have a text file which i need t read-in the values so the program can manipulate them.

Im using C++ and i have written working code to tell if the file exists or not.

The text file is formatted like this:

```
1    7
8    10
20   6
3    14
...
```

The values on the left are X values and the values on the right are Y values. (The space in the middle is a tab)
How do I extract this data? say to pass them into a class like this...

```
myVector(X,Y);
```

Also, I guess before I can use it in a class I have to TryParse to change it from a string to int right? can C++ do this?

Thank you!

Comment: TryParse is a C#-ism - are you sure you're programming in C++ here ?

Comment: std::getline in a loop.

Comment: Yep, Im comming from a C# background, I've used it there but didnt know if that was possible

Comment: They're completely different languages. I'd use scanf, or cin.

Comment: Yes I know. Thats why I need help with this problem. and cin wouldn't help with reading from a file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would be writing something like this if I were you. Note, this is just prototype code, and it was not even tested.

The fundamental idea is to read twice in a line, but with different delimiters. You would read with the tab delimiter first, and then just the default line end.

You need to make sure to gracefully quit the loop when you do not have anything more to read, hence the breaks, albeit the second could be enough if your file is "correct".

You will also need to make sure to convert to the proper type that your vector class expects. I assumed here that is int, but if it is string, you do not need the conversion I have put in place.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void yourFunction()
{
    ..
    ifstream myfile("myfile.txt");
    string xword, yword;
    while (1) {
        if (!getline(myfile, xword, '\t'))
            break;
        if (!getline(myfile, yword))
            break;
        myVector.push_back(stoi(xword), stoi(yword));
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is whatim looking for, Would it be possible to exlain your 'if' statements? Im a litle unsure what there doing

Comment: @user3012508: you need to quit the loop once you read everything in. Theoretically speaking, the second if statement could be enough if your file is "correct".

Comment: Where does it actually read in x and y?, and I do really appriciate the help

Comment: @user3012508 Check the documentation for `std:: getline` and you'll see that it returns an `istream &`. But, if you check the reference for `istream`, you'll see that there's a defined conversion to `bool`,  which returns false if there are no error flags set in the stream.  If there are error flags set, then break out of the loop.

Comment: @user3012508 The values are read in at the calls to `std:: getline`.  Note that `xword`, `yword` are passed to getline, which accepts a reference -- that it, it modifies those values.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of parsing could be done in one line with boost.spirit:

```
qi::phrase_parse(begin, end, *(qi::int_ > qi::int_ > qi::eol), qi::ascii::blank, v);
```

The grammar could be read as: "read one int, then one int, then one EOL (end of line) (\n or \r\n, depends on locale), as many time as possible". Between ints and EOL can be found blank characters (e.g. spaces or tabs).

Advantages: rather than std::getline loops, code is more clear/concise. spirit.qi get you more powerful control and you don't need stoi calls.
Drawbacks: build-depends (no depends) to spirit.qi, compilation time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/std_pair.hpp>

namespace spirit = boost::spirit;
namespace qi = spirit::qi;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::ifstream in(argv[1], std::ios_base::in);

  std::string storage;
  in.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
  spirit::istream_iterator begin(in), end;

  std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > v;
  qi::phrase_parse(begin, end, *(qi::int_ > qi::int_ > qi::eol), qi::ascii::blank, v);

  for(const auto& p : v)
    std::cout << p.first << "," << p.second << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```